# Filter BehaviorRelay array rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, observable

I have a `BehaviorRelay` with an Array of `FamilyTaskCoreData` inside it. In `FamilyTaskCoreData` I have the "owner" parameter and I want to filter the Array where it has the id of `"45332523dqwd"` or an other query.

This is my `BehaviorRelay`:

```swift
private var familyTask = BehaviorRelay<[FamilyTasksCoreData]>(value: [])
```

And this is the code I use to bind it:

```swift
let item = memberData.getTaskData(memberID: queryID)

    item
    .filter(
        $0.filter{ $0.name.hasPrefix("M")}
    )
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "familyCleaningPlanCell", cellType: FamilyCleaningPlanTableViewCell.self)) {[weak self] (row, element, cell) in

        cell.titleLabel.text = element.title
        cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected = element.status
        cell.categoryImage.image = self?.defineImage(name: element.category ?? "")

        self?.updateAnItem(cell: cell, data: element)

    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

I tried to filter it with the filter statement...because I saw it on another question, but I can't find something after $0.. in my case there is no value which I can select.

FamilyTasksCoreData:

```
@NSManaged public var category: String?
@NSManaged public var end: Date
@NSManaged public var id: String?
@NSManaged public var start: Date
@NSManaged public var status: Bool
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var createdAt: Date
@NSManaged public var owner: String?
@NSManaged public var familyID: String?
```

Comment: what type of variable is item ? whats inn it ? show that please

Comment: inside: FamilyTaskCoreData Object: @NSManaged public var category: String?
    NSManaged public var end: Date
    NSManaged public var id: String?
    NSManaged public var start: Date
    NSManaged public var status: Bool
    NSManaged public var title: String?
    NSManaged public var createdAt: Date
    NSManaged public var owner: String?

Comment: please add it in question

Comment: done.. would be great if you have an approach

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the tableView to only show FamilyTasksCoreData objects that have a name beginning with "M".

To do that, you need to use a `map` on the relay instead of a `filter`. If you use a `filter` on the relay, you will filter out the entire array all at once, instead of the individual elements.

Instead, you want to use `map` to *transform* each array you get from the relay, filtering out the elements that do not begin with "M".

Your code should look something like this:

```
item
    .map {
        $0.filter { $0.name.hasPrefix("M") }
    }
    .bind(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single filter to filter your array

```
item.filter{ $0.owner.hasPrefix("M")}
```